# How to use LEA in 80x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have this line of code in 80x86 assembly:

```
.DATA  
string BYTE 22 DUP  (?)   
.CODE  
input string,22  
lea EBX,string
```

I want to compare the bytes of the string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LEA` instruction is used to load an address into a register, and it can additionally also do some calculations, which are related to indexing an array.

In your example you already loaded the address into `EBX`.
Now you can access the characters of your string like this:

```
mov al, byte ptr [ebx]
```

However, if you just want to compare a string you should know that in `x86` assembly there are instructions available which can compare a length of memory. In order to do this you load the maximum length in `ECX`, the first pointer into `ESI` and the second in `EDI`. Then you can use the `cmps[x]` (x being the operand size [b]yte, [w]ord or [d]word) in conjunction with the `rep` prefix to loop through the memory until you hit a  byte matching matching the condition, or `ecx` becomes zero.

An example:

```
 mov ecx, maxsize        ; maximum length of the memory that should be compared
 mov ebx, ecx
 lea esi, first_string   ; Pointer to first array to be compared
 lea edi, second_string  ; Pointer to second array to be compared
 repe cmpsb              ; Loop until either ecx is 0 or the bytes are different
 sub ebx, ecx            ; ebx will now have the number of bytes that matched.
```

Note that the `ecx` is decreased, so if you want to know the length of the matching segment, you'd have to subtract the original length. if you just want to know if the strings were equal, then you can simply check if `ecx` is zero.

If you want to do more complex checking you can still use these instructions without the `rep` prefix and still take advantage of the string instructions, because it also increases `ESI`

For example:

```
    mov ecx, maxlen
    lea esi, string

 @@StringCmp:
    lodsb            ; Load the byte from DS:ESI to AL and increase ESI

    ; Byte is now in AL and you can do whatever you need with it.

    loop @@StringCmp
```

Answer (score 0):

`EBX` is already a pointer, ie, an address. Just:

```
mov EBX, string
```

The `LEA` instruction is to load the address of a complex indirection argument.

Comment: i want to use [EBX] for the first character

Comment: `mov ebx,string` would work for loading the address of the string in NASM syntax. If the OP is using MASM or TASM it would be `mov ebx,offset string`.

Comment: @Sina: You want `lea EBX, [string]` but AFAIK that doesn't exist. And if it did it would be exactly equivalent to `move EBX, string`.